# kaminari + bootstrap の色を変えたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

rails で kaminari を用いてページネーションを実装しました。
rails g kaminari:views bootstrap でbootstrapを使ったデザインにしたのですが
cssから配色を変更しようとしています。

それで、文字色を変更するところまではできたのですが、
選択されているページ( http://bit.ly/1niuhcS の「1」のところ）の
背景色を動かすことができず困っています。
この色は、background-color で変わりますか？
それならば、セレクタの指定の問題かなとなるのですが、
その切り分けもできず、暗礁に乗り上げております。
どの属性で制御されているか、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: background-color で変わるはずです。`.pagination a { background: red }` ではダメだったということでしょうか？

Comment: http://bit.ly/1TWl86t 画像のようになって、肝心の「１」の回りの青はそのままになっています……。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現在選択されているページには、`.current` がつくので、それを上書きすれば良いのではないでしょうか？

```
.pagination .current { background: red }
```

貴方の html の状態によりますので、html のソースを見ることをお勧めします。

[Web開発でよく使う、特に使えるChromeデベロッパー・ツールの機能 - Build Insider](http://www.buildinsider.net/web/chromedevtools/01)

Comment: .pagination .active a {  background-color: red }

でいけました！

なんべんもありがとうございます。助かりました。